# How to rewrite nested object in model while update

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have a problem with update object nested in array ("companyBases"), because update scripts overwrites my nested object, i have the following model:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d6504541be1e64145c20c66"),
    "margin" : 10,
    "defaultDeprication" : 10,
    "companyBases" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d6504541be1e64145c20c64"),
            "name" : "Tech Parking 2",
            "street" : "Traktat Ojca",
            "postalCode" : "30-856",
            "city" : "Cracow",
            "location" : {
                "lng" : 50.036017,
                "lat" : 20.086752
            },
            "__v" : 0
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d6504541be1e64145c20c65"),
            "name" : "Tech Parking 3",
            "street" : "ul.Bieżanowska 258B",
            "postalCode" : "30-856",
            "city" : "Cracow",
            "location" : {
                "lng" : 50.01744,
                "lat" : 20.033522
            },
            "__v" : 0
        }
    ],
}
```

I'am executing update query:

```
db.companies.updateOne(
          {
            _id: ObjectId("5d6504541be1e64145c20c66"),
            "companyBases._id": ObjectId("5d6504541be1e64145c20c64")
          },
          {
            $set: {
              "companyBases.$": {
                    "street" : "ul.Małapolska 123"
                  }

            }
          }
        )
```

But it overwrites my nested object and now it looking like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d6504541be1e64145c20c66"),
    "margin" : 10,
    "defaultDeprication" : 10,
    "companyBases" : [
        {
            "street" : "ul.Małapolska 123"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d6504541be1e64145c20c65"),
            "name" : "Tech Parking 3",
            "street" : "ul.Bieżanowska 258B",
            "postalCode" : "30-856",
            "city" : "Cracow",
            "location" : {
                "lng" : 50.01744,
                "lat" : 20.033522
            },
            "__v" : 0
        }
    ],
}
```

I would like to rewrite all field from nested object and update fields that i choose in update query.

It should looks like this (without overwriting whole object):

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d6504541be1e64145c20c66"),
    "margin" : 10,
    "defaultDeprication" : 10,
    "companyBases" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d6504541be1e64145c20c64"),
            "name" : "Tech Parking 2",
            "street" : "ul.Małapolska 123",
            "postalCode" : "30-856",
            "city" : "Cracow",
            "location" : {
                "lng" : 50.036017,
                "lat" : 20.086752
            },
            "__v" : 0
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d6504541be1e64145c20c65"),
            "name" : "Tech Parking 3",
            "street" : "ul.Bieżanowska 258B",
            "postalCode" : "30-856",
            "city" : "Cracow",
            "location" : {
                "lng" : 50.01744,
                "lat" : 20.033522
            },
            "__v" : 0
        }
    ],
}
```

Comment: change  "companyBases.$": {
                    "street" : "ul.Małapolska 123"
                  } to "comapnyBases.$.street": "ul.Małapolska 123" 

you're updating wrong as you are replacing array elem with {street:"ul.Małapolska 123"} instead of updating a single key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use arrayFilter in the update operation, as described here: 
[positinal filter for arrays](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/)

```
db.companies.updateOne(
      {
        _id: ObjectId("5d6504541be1e64145c20c66"),
      },
      {
        $set: {
          "companyBases.$[element].street: "ul.Małapolska 123"
        }
      },
      {
        arrayFilters: [ {"element._id": ObjectId("5d6504541be1e64145c20c64")} ]
      }
    )
```

Comment: It' doesn't work, query retruns me: {
 "acknowledged" : true,
 "matchedCount" : 1,
 "modifiedCount" : 0
}, first _id is _id of docuement and second (in element: ....) it's _id of nested object ?

Comment: you are right, my bad: it suppose to be "element._id" on the arrayFilters line, ill update my answer (hopefully it will help)

Comment: You have only one error - it should be: "companyBases.$[element].street": "ul.Małapolska 123" not "companyBases.$[element].street: "ul.Małapolska 123"